# Parsing book sources with Regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string-parsing

I am currently building a parser that is supposed to extract different sources from an absolute mess :) I've been working on it for a couple of days and it's working just fine. However, I encountered a serious problem when trying to parse the last segments of a book. There is no character that can really help me separating stuff:

```
var str = 'John Doe, Max Mustermann, Taro Tanaka, My Mean Title: Some titles are just totally, absolutely, and unnecessarily mean';
```

As you can see, the string contains names separated by a comma and a title that contains a comma but does not require quotes around it. Also, there are similar versions in my testdata which look like this:

```
var str = 'John Doe, Max Mustermann, Taro Tanaka: My Mean Title: Some titles are just totally, absolutely, and unnecessarily mean';
```

This doesn't make it easier. What I want is to store the book's title in an object (which already contains date, publisher,...) and, afterwards, remove the title from the source string. I'd be very happy if someone could help me out :)

Here's a fiddle to play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/TheFatalist/927645vz/1/
However, I'd recommend using this tool: http://leaverou.github.io/regexplained/

Thanks a lot in advance! I will update the fiddle, as soon as I can figure something out.

Edit: To avoid confusion: I am searching for the regex that separates title and name. Or another workaround. I hope there is some kind of way to identify this... but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: How can we help if you don't have a specific rule (or rules) for which part of the string is the title?

Comment: That's what I'm searching for!

Comment: Is there no text we could use, I mean does the title always have the prefix: "Title:" or something in front of it?

Comment: Nope. It's the way that the authors entered their sources. That was way before it was decided to parse these things.

Comment: So given that any given book may have multiple authors and multiple commas and colons (or, presumably, no colons or commas) in the title I'm not sure that this can be done at all reliably.

Comment: Well, an approximation would be enough :) But yes, that's what I'm afraid of.

Comment: If you can't provide any guarantee of the format, it is not possible for us to do anything other than guess at a solution.

Comment: Which is what I'm doing at the moment. Really, the above examples are what I have to work with. I'm sorry - but I didn't write the sources down :/

Comment: Regexes are not going to help you here (except for the basic tokenizing). No regex would be able to parse "Kristen McDermott, William Shakespeare: His Life and Times" correctly. This can only be done, more or less reliably, by the means of machine learning (e.g. probabilistic classification).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will try to learn more about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @nnnnnn states it's hard to do this in a very reliable manner but may get somewhere when you try to match from the end of the string:

```js
var str = 'John Doe, Max Mustermann, Taro Tanaka, My Mean Title: Some titles are just totally, absolutely, and unnecessarily mean';
var str2 = 'John Doe, Max Mustermann, Taro Tanaka: My Mean Title: Some titles are just totally, absolutely, and unnecessarily mean';

// assume all characters after semicolon as title and include all characters and whitespace before the semicolon
// everything before the title is assumed to be authors
var regex = /(.*?)((\w|\s)+:[^:]+)$/;

var str_match = regex.exec(str);
$('body').append('<br>string: "'+str+'"<br>title: '+ str_match[2]+'<br>authors: '+str_match[1]);

$('body').append('<br><br>');

var str2_match = regex.exec(str2);
$('body').append('<br>string: "'+str2+'"<br>title: '+ str2_match[2]+'<br>authors: '+str2_match[1]);
```

Comment: It's not perfect but it's way better than everything I came up with so far. Thank you! I will wait to mark this as answered, because others might have a look at it still. I won't forget it though, thanks again :)

Comment: Thanks again. With this, I found a workaround that works okay. For my case, this was the right answer. Thanks to everybody who tried to solve my problem with me!

Answer (score 1):

```
^(.*?)(?:,(?=[^,]*:)|\s(?=\w+:))(.*)$
```

Try this.Grab the matches.Match `2` contains `title detail`

Or simply use regex.split to get your results with this re.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kM7rT8/5

Comment: Also not bad, even though the other solution (Tom Ritsema's) works in more cases. Again: Thank you so much! :)

Comment: "Hans Behrbohm er. Al: Kurzlehrbuch Hals-Nasen-Ohrenheilkunde"

Edit: [Hans Behrbohm er. Al] is the name, [Kurzlehrbuch...] is the title

I am sorry that I did not post this case earlier. I thought it well covered.

Comment: @sb try now and do let me know if some cases fail

Comment: Yes, again: "Herbert Hof, Rüdiger Dörries: Medizinische Mikrobiologie". Thanks for all your effort, though - it's appreciated! I found a workaround which works okay, using Ritsema's regex.